# Problem iterating through MongoDB data using Flask & Jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

brand new to Flask/Python and i'm trying to iterate through a list of data from MongoDB using Flask. The data is grabbed with no issues but the result i get is all of the database entries stuffed into one div. Below i've provided some screenshots to further explain the problem.

**The 2 MongoDB Entries:**
[image]
The idea is to have 2 separate cards displaying the 2 entries. The card will display the `name_moving`, once clicked, the rest of the info will appear in a modal.

**HTML Template Code:**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal request_info_wrap">
            {% for user_details in user_details: %}
            <div class="modal-content request_info_card">

                <h4 class="request_name_header">{{ user_details.user_name }} {{ user_details.user_lname }}</h4>
                <p class="request_info"><span class="request_title">Request
                        Address:</span><br>{{ user_details.user_street }}<br>{{ user_details.user_postcode }}</p><br>
                <p class="request_info"><span class="request_title">Contact
                        Number:</span><br>{{ user_details.user_contact }}</p><br>
                <p class="request_info"><span class="request_title">Requested
                        Date:</span><br>{{ user_details.user_date }}</p><br>
                <div class="deep_clean_section">
                    <p class="request_info" style="color: #000;"><span class="request_title">Deep Clean
                            for:</span><br>{{ user_details.carpet_clean }}<br>{{ user_details.floor_steam }}<br>
                        {{ user_details.white_goods }}<br>{{ user_details.window_clean }}
                    </p>
                </div><br>
                <hr style="margin: 0;">
                <p class="request_info"><span class="request_title">Customer
                        Message:</span><br>{{ user_details.user_message }}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer job_card_btn_wrap">
                <a href="#" class="modal-close replyto_btn">Reply to
                    {{ user_details.user_name }}</a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue i'm having is that both entries show within the same `div` (shown below) whereas im trying to get each MondoDB entry to show individually when clicked.

[image]

**Python/Flask Code:**

```
@app.route("/deep_clean_info", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def deep_clean_info():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_details = {
            "user_name": request.form.get("user_name"),
            "user_lname": request.form.get("user_lname"),
            "user_contact": request.form.get("user_contact"),
            "user_street": request.form.get("user_street"),
            "user_postcode": request.form.get("user_postcode"),
            "user_message": request.form.get("user_message"),
            "user_date": request.form.get("user_date"),
            "carpet_clean": request.form.get("carpet_clean"),
            "floor_steam": request.form.get("floor_steam"),
            "white_goods": request.form.get("white_goods"),
            "window_clean": request.form.get("window_clean"),
        }
        mongo.db.user_details.insert_one(user_details)
        flash("Request sent to cleaner")
        return redirect(url_for("deep_clean_info"))
    details = mongo.db.user_details.find().sort("user_details", 1)
    return render_template("deep_clean_details.html", user_details=details)
```

I do think the issue is with my jinja2 for loop in my template but any help would be greatly appreciated, also if any additional information is needed i'll be more than happy to provide. Thanks!

**EDIT**
HTML Template that seemed to iterate fine, although i dont want to use this style to display the data.

```
<ul class="collapsible popout pending_jobs">
        {% for user_details in user_details %}
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header request_item_header">
                <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
                {{ user_details.user_name }} {{ user_details.user_lname }}

            </div>

            <div class="collapsible-body request_info">
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="row info_headers">Address:<br>
                        <span class="light_text info_text" id="customer_address">
                            {{ user_details.user_street }}</span>
                    </span><br>
                    <span class="info_headers">Contact Number:<br>
                        <span class="light_text info_text" id="customer_contact">{{ user_details.user_contact }}</span>
                    </span><br>
                </div>
                <span class="info_headers row customer_request_style">Customer Request:<br>
                    <span class="light_text italic_text" id="customer_request">{{ user_details.user_message }}</span>
                </span><br>
                <span class="info_headers">Cleaning Date:<br>
                    <span class="light_text italic_text" id="customer_request">{{ user_details.user_date }}</span>
                </span><br>
                <a href="{{ url_for('cleaner_chat') }}"><button class="respond_to_user">Respond to
                        {{ user_details.user_name }}?</button></a>

                     

            </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: please share code/data and not images

Comment: @balderman Apologies, i've updated the screenshots with the code.

Comment: `{% for user_details in user_details %}` is that a bug?

Comment: Your outer for loop is using the same variable name for the item as for the iterator. might that mess things up?

Comment: try something like:     `{% for user_details in user_details_lst %}`

Comment: @balderman for some reason i can no longer view the details grabbed when changing to ```{% for user_details in user_details_list %}```. I also change the python code to match but still no results.

Comment: did you change the code to` return render_template("deep_clean_details.html", user_details_lst=details)` ?

Comment: @balderman Yep, tried that with the same results. Just to add, this iteration seems to work fine with another style of card i was using previously. It stops working when using the modal style im attempting to use here. I've updated the question with the template that seems to iterate fine.